# How to run custom Javascript on Wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltoimage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wkhtmltopdf, wkhtmltoimage

I want to run a javascript on a website, but when I do it, nothing changes, I get the pdf as if I run no result of the javascript on it, this is an example of what I do:

```
xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0, 1024x768x24" wkhtmltoimage --run-script "javascript:(\$(function(){ \$("div").hide()   ;}))" google.com google.png
```

I have also scripts without jquery like:

```
xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0, 1024x768x24" wkhtmltopdf --run-script "javascript:(function(){ document.write("AHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH"); ;})" google.com p2.pdf
```

But as I said, no effect on the pdf or the png (because I have tried both wkhtmltoimage and wkhtmltopdf).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your command uses quotes incorrectly; try this:

```
--run-script "javascript:(\$(function(){ \$('div').hide()   ;}))"
```

Also, try increasing the JavaScript delay:

```
--javascript-delay 1000
```

http://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved the problem, by the way, do you know any way of generate a .png with less size? cause every png I generate weights 9MB, again, thank you

Answer (score 5):

About the question

> "do you know any way of generate a .png with less size? cause every png I generate weights 9MB"

I had the same problem with large PNG files generated with wkhtmltoimage and managed to fix this with adding the flag `--quality 0`, that shrunk the image from 3.5MB to just 38KB. Note that PNG is doing lossless compression so the image quality won't change only will be shrunk in size. Be careful when using `--quality` flag when you output to jpg format as this can blur the image is you set it too low.

Comment: Can confirm, went from 10mb to 70kb